# How to add alt tag to images in blogger

Tags: seo, keyword, blogger, alt, image-optimization

I have came to know we can use the alt tag for better seo but iam confusing about the using of alt tag to my images.

I mean can we use - symbol between the keywords like facebook-tips-tricks or should i only use facebook tips tricks.

I have came to know google will also crawl images but how can we effectively implement in images in blogger posts.

Comment: Don't keyword stuff alt *attributes*. Use them for their intended purpose - as alternative text for people who can't see the image.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to use the `-` symbol. You need to simply put the alternate. Google will do it's work.

Example:

```html
<html> 
  <body>
    <img src="http://theartmad.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Smiley-Face-7.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42"><!-- Will normally show the image, since path is valid -->
    <img src="invalid path" alt="X" height="42" width="42"> <!-- Will show the alt, since there's no valid path. Will work without -'s. -->
    </body>
  </html>
```

As mentioned in the comments, you might want to read more about the purpouse of the `alt` attribute. You can do so [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp)

Comment: but i have seen many of the wordpress site users use this feature i mean this - symbol it does effect or we can also add the symbol ...?

Comment: @Seostuff There's no diffrence if you use the `-`'s or not. It's up to personal preferance. If you'd like to have them, you can, and If you dont want them, you can just use spaces instead. I personally prefer the latter As far as I'm concerned, there's no diffrence SEO wise.

Comment: thank you abramov for your suggestion thanks once again it helped me

Comment: @Seostuff If it did, mark this as the answer. I'm glad to hear. :)